# Convert integer array to binary representation matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 1d integer array, e.g.:

`[1, 0, -1]`

looking for a binary representation matrix, desired output:

`[[0 1], [0 0], [1 1]]`

possibly using [np.binary_repr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.binary_repr.html) with a given fixed width. Currently `np.binary_repr` gives back a string and only applies to a single number at a time.

```
tobin = np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)
tobin(np.arange(4))
# ['0000' '0001' '0010' '0011']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.unpackbits](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html):

```
a=np.array([-1,0,1]) # dtype is np.int32
```

You have to input your data as `np.uint8` because that is the only data type supported by unpackbits:

```
bi = np.unpackbits(a[:,None].view(np.uint8), axis=1)
```

Original input data is 32bit, so you get 32 values per input element, crop accordingly (keeping in mind min/max values in `a`):

```
result = bi[:, :8]
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

## Edit:

This works well for small numbers like the one in the answer. If you need more than 8 bits, you should read the 1st 8 elements of `bi` and then the 16th to 8th elements. It's a bit messy.

For a more generic solution, just better flip the array `view`. And cropping before unpacking will give you a some performance improvement:

```
def int_to_bin(arr, n_bytes=1):       
    # arr is 1-D
    arr_ = np.fliplr(arr[:, None].view(np.uint8))[:, -n_bytes:]        
    return np.unpackbits(arr_, axis=1)
```

You can crop the output further if you want, say, only 4 bits. This takes about 10 ms for one million `arr` of `int32`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had initially in mind but it needs to be able to handle arbitrary bits, not in bytes.

Comment: The minimum memory that np uses to represent an `int` is one byte. I think that's because of hardware, so under the hood, you are getting 8 bits whether you want them all or not. For arbitrary bits, you can simply index what you need: `int_to_bin(a)[:, -4:]` for 4 bits

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explicit for loop based solution I currently have, would be keen on getting a vectorised solution.

```
def int_to_bin_matrix(arr: np.ndarray, width: int):
  """Return the binary representation of matrix of integer array."""
  return np.array([[int(c) for c in np.binary_repr(i, width=width)] for i in arr], dtype=np.int32)

print(int_to_bin_matrix(np.arange(-2,2), 4))

[[1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```